# System Diagnostics Log Creation in WCF Calls not working

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, wcf-data-services, system.diagnostics

I'm having a WCF Service for my WPF Application. I wish to monitor what are all the call which I was received from the Client Application.

I read one article http://dotnetmentors.com/how-to-enable-wcf-tracing-and-wcf-message-loging.aspx regarding WCF Tracing.

I used the same code in my WCF Web.Config

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="All"
                propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="d:\logs\messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="false" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

But I can't create any file in the said location **`d:\logs\messages.svclog`**.

Kindly assist me how to get the log files.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sections you need to add, namely your sources in the system.diagnostics and the messagelogging under your system.serviceModal section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\WcfMessageTrace.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```